# Удаление в input лишний цифры телефонного номера на javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

Есть `input` в который пользователь вводит номер телефона:

`<input placeholder="Номер телефона" autofocus="autofocus" type="tel" autocomplete="new-password" name="phone" id="phone_number"/>`

Используется jQuery Masked Input Plugin Version: 1.4.1

У `input` есть маска, где уже проставлен **+7**:  `+7(___)___-__-__`

`if (!$.browser.msie && !parseInt($.browser.version)<7) {$('#phone_number').mask("+7(999)999-99-99");}`

Иногда пользователь не замечает этот **+7** и вводит после него лишнюю "**8**" Например: +7(**8**91)234-45-67. И я получаю некорректный номер, без последней цифры.

Удалять автоматом цифру 8 нельзя, тк есть городские номера, например код СПБ +7812...
А вот номеров +789... вроде в России нет.

Требуется авто удаление цифры 8 в начале номера, если после нее стоит цифра 9, что бы `+7(89_ ) ___ - __ -__` превратился в `+7( 9__ ) ___ - __ - __`

Вот мое решение, оно работает, но удаляет еще и введенную цифру 9, что нежелательно:

```
    $('#phone_number').on('change keyup', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var digit = ('' + val)[3]; 
    var digit2 = ('' + val)[4];
    if (digit == '8' && digit2 == '9') {$(this).blur(); $(this).focus();}
  });
```

Как в `+7(89...` удалять цифру 8, но оставить 9 и установить курсор после 9?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете плагин Mask то только так

```
$('#phone_number').on('change keyup', function() {

    var str = $(this).val();

    if(str.charAt(3) === '8')
    {
        if(str.charAt(4) === '9'){
            var str = str.slice(0, 3) + str.slice(4);
            $(this).val(str)
            $("input").caret(0,5)
        }
    }

});
```

К сожалению не получится сделать на 100% как вы хотите так как данный плагин использует свою реализацию записи данных в поле input. $("input").caret(0,5) это метод плагина Mask который перемещает курсор. Другими словами если мы удаляем цифру 8 то плагин Mask все равно его хранит в своей памяти и использует хоть мы и даем команду удалить цифру 8 и записать значение в поле без цифры 8 а плагин Mask все равно перезапишет это поле. В любом случае попробуйте поэкспереминтировать